# IE8 not displaying Img element correctly when a large height attribute is defined

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I have an image element like the following

```
<img src="someImage.jpg" height="26136" width="918" />
```

In IE8, this image does not render correctly. The height of the rendered image is squished down into what looks like 1 pixel. However, if I instead set the height by CSS styles, the image is rendered correctly.

Comment: Did you mean height="26136" width="918"?

Comment: Assuming `918 * 26136`, warning: http://i.imgur.com/M2Olq.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As in the comment, I made this test image:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Olq.jpg  - *I'm not going to inline it here :)*

I'm testing with bona fide Internet Explorer 8 / Windows 7.

This test has your described behaviour:

http://jsfiddle.net/K5ydt/

I kept tweaking the `height` to try to find the limit. When I got to it working with `16000`, but not working with `17000`, I tried the number `16384`, which is the maximum value of some integer data type (or something like that, I can't remember precisely what).

And sure enough:

- [`16384` works](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ydt/1/).
- [`16385` does not work.](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ydt/2/)

I couldn't find a way to "fix" this, and there probably isn't one. I think you'll have to [use this](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ydt/5/) instead:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Olq.jpg" style="width:918px; height: 26136px" />
```

Also, [not specifying dimensions](http://jsfiddle.net/K5ydt/6/) works:

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2Olq.jpg" />
```

---

Interestingly, IE9 also appears to suffer from the same problem.

I tested with http://ipinfo.info/netrenderer/ + http://fiddle.jshell.net/K5ydt/show/light/ - the result: a `1px` high image.

Comment: So 16384 is 16KB, but I can't seem to find a reference to what integer data type that is a limit of. I agree that I need to use a style instead, but I still don't understand why 16384 is the limit.

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but I *guess* they're using half the capacity of a signed [short](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short_integer) (or their own type?). I also can't find any solid reference on the Internet about this limit in IE to help me out. It's clearly a bug they could fix relatively easily - I guess that not many people actually run into it; and those that do will simply switch to using the CSS properties.