# why is this jpg image not showing up in IE 7 and 8

Tags: html, css, wordpress, internet-explorer

for some reason this image, which is a jpg isn't showing up in IE7 or 8... here is the php:

```
<img src="<?php echo get_option('logo');?>" alt="logo" height="70px" width="405px" />
```

and the output (which doesn't end the image tag for some reason):

```
<img src="http://guardianweb.edulence.com/fosterklima/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/guardian-4-color.jpg" alt="logo" height="70px" width="405px">
```

live url: http://guardianweb.edulence.com/fosterklima/

EDIT*** the image has been resized to 400 x 70 and still isn't working...

Comment: The image is huge - have you tried scaling it down to the correct size first?

Comment: yeah, i just resized it and it's still not working

Comment: Hmmm, related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5709330/ie8-not-displaying-img-element-correctly-when-a-large-height-attribute-is-define?

Comment: tried setting the style, but it's still not working... also i resized the image so it's much smaller. it wasn't as big as the 16384 in that post anyways

Comment: How did you resize it ? With what program ?

Comment: This is rather old... but it is possible the JPG image was saved using CMYK instead of RGB?
http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/jpeg-problems-in-firefox-and-ie/

Comment: Did you fix it? It seems to be working in IE9/8 ... By the image, I presume you mean the Guardian logo?

Comment: @JeffBridgman it worked!! thanks so much, i've seen this once a while ago, but didn't even think about it

Comment: @JeffBridgman - You should make this an answer.

Comment: @KeganQuimby Your welcome! Posted my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Although this [article](http://www.mattcutts.com/blog/jpeg-problems-in-firefox-and-ie/) is rather old, it might be of use.

If the JPG image was saved using CMYK instead of RGB it may have trouble displaying. It looks like the older versions of IE (and Firefox) have a problem with this.

Comment: Chrome will also display CMYK images differently than RGB images. I had a client upload a CMYK image recently and the colours looked differently when Chrome rendered it.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with the HTML markup you are referring to, and the missing `/` at the end of your image is there in the source code.

However this image is massive compared to the size of the image element, which will slow loading time down.

I would recommend you resize the image to `405px * 70px` so that it fits in the `img` element without the browser needing to resize it for you (which will cause distortion).

Comment: yeah the image is now resized, and it's still not working. i see the ending / in IE9, but it doesnt appear in chrome or the other IE's

Answer (score 0):

Your image is too big. IE doesn't show images that are way too big. You should make a copy and scale it down to `405px * 70px` and then change your HTML to point to the new image.

---

Nothing wrong with the HTML. And it shows up on Google Chrome, Firefox.

[image: Proof]

Comment: @KeganQuimby This is very strange. Might be something with the server because your image doesn't show up at http://guardianweb.edulence.com/fosterklima/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/guardian-4-color1.jpg in IE

Comment: other jpgs show up tho... try http://guardianweb.edulence.com/fosterklima/wp-content/uploads/2012/04/Foster-LOGO.jpg

Comment: @Kegan I know but still, maybe something with that specific image?

Comment: it was saved using CMYK and not RGB... all fixed now tho

Comment: @KeganQuimby How? By changing CMYK to RGB?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/10708/discussion-between-kegan-quimby-and-anish-gupta)